# BeanList deferred Play framework 2.0 + java

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I created two `Entity` : `User` and `Post`

A user can have many post so i add `@OnetoMany` for `User` and `@ManytoOne` for `Post`

USER.JAVA ---

```
@Entity
public class Users extends Model{

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Constraints.Required
    @NotNull
    public String username;

    @Constraints.Required
    @NotNull
    @Constraints.Email
    public String email;

    @Constraints.Required
    @Constraints.MinLength(6)
    @NotNull
    public String password;


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    public List<Post> post;

    public Users(){}

    public Users(String username,String email,String password){
        this.username=username;
        this.email=email;
        this.password=password;
        this.post=new ArrayList<Post>();
    }
}
```

and POST.JAVA ---

```
    @Entity
    public class Post extends Model{

        @Id
        public Long id;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
        public Users user;

        public String title;

        public String article;
}
```

When i search user's information and display it like :

```
@(users : List[Users])
@for(user <- users){
    @user.post</br>
    @user.username</br>
    @user.password</br>
    @user.email</a>
}
```

"BeanList deferred" appeared. (Not error, not exception , just a `String`)

Result :

```
BeanList deferred  // like this
Kenny
123456
kennybg@gmail.com
```

Any help, any ideal or some way for me can link two entities ?

Comment: What did you expect the @user.post to display? You'll have to handle it correctly, for example displaying the size of the list if that's what you want (which sounds like the most logical thing to do. I doubt you want to display all the contents of the posts of the person there).

Comment: @ Kayaman : I want to display "article" in Post. i try @user.post.article but got this error : value article is not a member of java.util.List[models.Post]

Comment: You have a list of Users objects (poorly named class btw, it should be User) which contains a list of Post objects. You're iterating only one list but not the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I.e. you'll need to do something like:

```
@(users : List[Users])
@for(user <- users){
    for(post <- user.post) {
        @post.article<br/>
    }
    @user.post</br>
    @user.username</br>
    @user.password</br>
    @user.email</a>
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kayaman for you example. But i got this error : "not found: value post" Can u miss or i lost something ? . If user:Form[User], i can get "article" by : @user.post.article right?

Comment: Sry Kayaman. I forgot @ before for() :) It's worked fine. Thank you very much